# it's correct create multiple classes in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hi i have a question because i usually use multiple classes in Ruby but i dont know if is that correct?, for example the next code:

Class Main.rb

```
class Main
 require_relative 'Archivo.rb'
 require_relative 'Diccionario.rb'
 require_relative 'Jsn.rb'

 hsh = Diccionario.new
 jsn = Jsn.new
 fl = Archivo.new

 puts "Ingresa Nombre"
 nombre = gets

 puts "Ingresa Correo"
 correo = gets

 puts "Ingresa password"
 password = gets


 hsh.usuario(nombre,correo,password)
 jsn.convert_json(hsh.get_usuario)
 fl.write('usuario.json',jsn.get_json)
 fl.read('usuario.json')
 puts fl.get_line

end
```

Class Diccionario.rb in other file

```
class Diccionario
  $usuarios = Hash.new
  require 'json'
  def usuario(nombre, correo, password)
     $usuarios = {nombre: nombre, correo: correo, password: password}
  end

  def get_usuario
    $usuarios
  end
end
```

Class Jsn.rb in other file

```
class Jsn
 require 'json'
 $cadena
 def convert_json(cadena)
  $cadena = cadena.to_json
 end

 def get_json
   $cadena
 end

end
```

Class Archivo.rb in other file

```
class Archivo
$line
 def read(file)
   File.open(file,"r") {|archivo|
     $line =archivo.gets
   }
 end

 def write(file,cadena)
   File.open(file, "w+") do |f|
     f.puts cadena
   end
 end

 def get_line()
   $line.to_s
 end
end
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Sure, that's pretty normal.  Did you have any specific concerns?

Comment: well, I am not sure about your classes, but names of them seem to be bad enough. you should use international ( heh ) English language for names ( variables, classes, methods, etc. )

Comment: mgrant Not only that , and I noticed that many programmed in a single class = S, Thanks :D

Comment: gaussblurinc Ok , I write in Spanish because i don't speak english but is a good tip. Thanks :D

Comment: The way you're using them, the classes aren't adding any value - you are using global variables to store state rather than instances of your classes.

Comment: Should this go to CR or Programming?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be creating multiple classes! I would try to think in terms of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles to ascertain where behaviour belongs and which objects/classes have responsibility for implementing them.

There's an excellent book called Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby by Sandi Metz. It's a great book about how to organise your code into classes. It talks about SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) and how to drill down to the essence of the problem you're trying to solve. If you can't buy the book then there's a talk that covers the main points here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZh5LMaSmE

She actually mentions that it's a common error to "not create enough classes" and that you should feel confident to break the implementation down further to smaller manageable classes.

Comment: should not it be based on the actual logic of implementation that the number of classes be determined.I have seen some using modules more than classes.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I was just answering the specific question of whether the OP should use multiple classes in Ruby. I'm sure I'm not alone in having created a 500+ LOC User class and so, I believe that the tendency is to break classes down too little rather than too much.

Comment: i do agree to that :)

Comment: Sure divide and conquer apply also if there would not Object Oriented Programming , but my question was more oriented as to if it was right because in video tutorials had noticed that in one file created different classes, Thanks